# pyspark on emr with boto3, copy of s3 object result with Futures timed out after [100000 milliseconds]

Tags: pyspark, boto3, amazon-emr

I have a pyspark application that will transform csv to parquet and before this happen I'm copying some S3 object from a bucket to another.

pyspark with spark 2.4, emr 5.27, maximizeResourceAllocation set to true

I have various csv files size, from 80kb to 500mb.

Nonetheless, my EMR cluster (it doesn't fail on local with spark-submit) fails at 70% completion on a file that is 166mb (a previous at 480mb succeeded).

The job is simple:

```
def organise_adwords_csv():
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket(S3_ORIGIN_RAW_BUCKET)
    for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=S3_ORIGIN_ADWORDS_RAW + "/"):
        key = obj.key

        copy_source = {
            'Bucket': S3_ORIGIN_RAW_BUCKET,
            'Key': key
        }

        key_tab = obj.key.split("/")
        if len(key_tab) < 5:
            print("continuing from length", obj)
            continue
        file_name = ''.join(key_tab[len(key_tab)-1:len(key_tab)])
        if file_name == '':
            print("continuing", obj)
            continue

        table = file_name.split("_")[1].replace("-", "_")
        new_path = "{0}/{1}/{2}".format(S3_DESTINATION_ORDERED_ADWORDS_RAW_PATH, table, file_name)
        print("new_path", new_path) <- the last print will end here
        try:
            s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, S3_DESTINATION_RAW_BUCKET, new_path)
            print("copy done")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print("an exception occured while copying")

if __name__=='__main__':
    organise_adwords_csv()

    print("copy Final done") <- never printed

    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("adwords_transform") \
    ...
```

but, in the stdout, no  errors / exception are showing.

In stderr logs:

```
19/10/09 16:16:57 INFO ApplicationMaster: Waiting for spark context initialization...
19/10/09 16:18:37 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Uncaught exception: 
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [100000 milliseconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:468)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.org$apache$spark$deploy$yarn$ApplicationMaster$$runImpl(ApplicationMaster.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:779)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1844)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.doAsUser(ApplicationMaster.scala:778)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:803)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
19/10/09 16:18:37 INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 13, (reason: Uncaught exception: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [100000 milliseconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:468)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.org$apache$spark$deploy$yarn$ApplicationMaster$$runImpl(ApplicationMaster.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:779)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1844)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.doAsUser(ApplicationMaster.scala:778)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:803)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
)
19/10/09 16:18:37 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

I'm completely blind, I don't understand what is failing / why.
How can I figure that out? On local it works like a charm (but super slow of course)

**Edit:**
After many tries I can confirm that the function:

```
s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, S3_DESTINATION_RAW_BUCKET, new_path)
```

make the EMR cluster timeout, even tho it processed 80% of the files already.
Does anyone have a recommendation about this?

Comment: could you please try to launch spark-shell or pyspark on your EMR and see it come up properly or not then try to run script on the shell. For me it's look like your spark configuration has some problem

Comment: What I noticed is that this command: `s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, S3_DESTINATION_BUCKET, new_path)` is the one timing out.
I assume if the file to copy is too big spark will timeout..?

Answer (score 0):

```
s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, S3_DESTINATION_RAW_BUCKET, new_path)
```

This will fail for any source object larger than 5 GB. please use multipart upload in AWS. See https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#multipartupload

Comment: I don't have any object bigger than 3GB

Comment: the only way I had to "solve" it, is to add a time.sleep(3) every 60 files.